# What does ^ mean in react native package.json

Tags: react-native, package.json

I just want to upgrade some library in my project. I found that some dependencies have ^ in their version code like `"react-native-i18n": "^1.0.0"` but some don't have. I don't know what ^ means.

Comment: maybe your question can expalined on this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22343224/whats-the-difference-between-tilde-and-caret-in-package-json

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between tilde(~) and caret(^) in package.json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22343224/whats-the-difference-between-tilde-and-caret-in-package-json)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short its using for `Compatible with version`

you can check complete details on Semver

[Please check complete explanation here](https://bytearcher.com/articles/semver-explained-why-theres-a-caret-in-my-package-json/)

you can also check Package.json related documentation [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json)

Comment: Got it. Thanks @LoveTrivedi